# passing param to a method exposed from another controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to pass params to method declared in controller B, says it's conB.js and look like this

```
module.exports.verify = function(req,res,next){
// how to get it here?
}
```

Then now I'm have conA.js, how can I pass arguments to it?

I know firstly I have to include it,

```
var ConB = require('ConB');
```

but how to pass param to verify method like ConB.verify('param') so that I can get it in ConA.js?

Comment: can you explain what you actually want to do?

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary I want to pass param from controller to controller. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I undestand what you are trying to do but if you want to call verify with a parameter you have to define as a function accepting the parameter. So conB.js is:

```
module.exports.verify = function(param){
   // do something with param
   return something;
}
```

Then in conA.js:

```
var conB = require('./conB.js');
var result = conB.verify(your_param);
```

---

Update after comment...

You can also write the different controllers as express middleware and pass parameters along using res.locals. See: http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

In this case you need a route in you app that calls the middlewares in sequence:

```
app.use("/testUrl", consB.verify, cansA.doSomething);
```

Then consB.js is something like:

```
module.exports.verify = function(req, res, next){
   // do something with param and store something in res.locals
   res.locals.user = "foo";
   // then remember to call next
   next();
}
```

ConsA.js

```
module.exports.doSomething = function(req, res, next) {
    // use locals modified by previous middleware
    res.end("The user of the request is: "+res.locals.user);
}
```

Comment: where will my req,res,next be if I place multiple params into verify?

Comment: Do you need them inside verify? I'll update my answer, but without understanding what you are trying to do in verify it's difficult.

Answer (score 0):

file - conB.js

```
module.exports.verify = function(req,res,next){

}
```

file -  conA.js
//here you want to use exported object from conB.js

So what you can do this if both the files are in same folder otherwise you have to use relative paths.

```
 var conB = require('./conB.js')
```

Comment: I know how to do import and export, my question is how can I pass param.

Comment: export object like conB = { someName : function(req,res,next){ }}; and on other hand try conB.someName(yourParameters). i hope this will help.